# Why do we need a buffer while converting AVFrame from one format to another?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I am referring to [this](https://github.com/mpenkov/ffmpeg-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial01.c) source code . The code snippets provided here are from lines (114-138) in the code . This is using the ffmpeg library . Can anyone explain why is the following code required in the program ?

```
// Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
numBytes=avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_RGB24, pCodecCtx->width,
              pCodecCtx->height);
buffer=(uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));
```

In a sense I understand that the following function is associating the destination frame to the buffer . But what is the necessity ?

```
avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, buffer, PIX_FMT_RGB24, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
```

PS : I tried removing the buffer and compiling the program . It got compiled . But it is showing the following run time error .

> [swscaler @ 0xa06d0a0] bad dst image pointers
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think that what puzzles you is that there seem to be two allocations for AVFrame.

The first, done with `avcodec_alloc_frame()`, allocates the space for a generic frame and its metadata. At this point the memory required to hold the frame proper is still unknown.

You then populate that frame from another source, and it is then that you specify how much memory you need by passing `width`, `height` and color depth:

```
numBytes=avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_RGB24, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
```

At this point the frame and its content are two separate objects (an AVFrame and its *buffer*). You put them together with this code, which is not actually a *conversion* at all:

```
avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, buffer, PIX_FMT_RGB24,
pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
```

What the code above does is to "tell" `pFrameRGB`: " *you are a RGB-24 frame, this wide, this tall, and the memory you need is in 'buffer'* ".

Then and only then you can do whatever you want with `pFrameRGB`. Otherwise, you try to paint on a frame without the canvas, and the paint splashes down -- you get a core dump.

Once you have the frame (AVFrame) and the canvas (the buffer), you can use it:

```
// Read frames and save first five frames to disk
i=0;
while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) {
    // Is this a packet from the video stream?
    if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {
      // Decode video frame
      avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished,
&packet);
```

The above code extracts a video frame and decodes it into `pFrame` (which is native format). We could save `pFrame` to disk at this stage. We would not need `buffer`, and we could then not use `pFrameRGB`.

Instead we convert the frame to RGB-24 using `sws_scale()`.

To convert a frame into another format, we copy the source to a different destination. This is both because the destination frame could be bigger than what can be accommodated by the source frame, and because some conversion algorithms need to operate on larger areas of the untransformed source, so it would be awkward to transmogrify the source in-place. Also, the source frame is handled by the library and might conceivably not be safe to write to.

### Update (comments)

*What does the `data[]` of pFrame/pFrameRGB point to*: **initially, nothing**. They are NULL, and that is why using a noninitialized AVframe results in a core dump. You initialize them (and `linesize[]` etc.) using `avpicture_fill` (that fits in an empty buffer, plus image format and size information) or one of the decode functions (which do the same).

*Why does pFrame not require memory allocation*: good question. The answer is in the used function's [prototype and layout](http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/libavcodec_2utils_8c.html#eb2441bb9d76c881fc86a0085b2f13d2), where the *picture* parameter is described thus:

> The AVFrame in which the decoded video frame will be stored. Use
>   avcodec_alloc_frame to get an AVFrame, **the codec will allocate memory
>   for the actual bitmap**. with default get/release_buffer(), the decoder
>   frees/reuses the bitmap as it sees fit. with overridden
>   get/release_buffer() (needs CODEC_CAP_DR1) the user decides into what
>   buffer the decoder decodes and the decoder tells the user once it does
>   not need the data anymore, the user app can at this point
>   free/reuse/keep the memory as it sees fit.

Comment: I am getting confused :D .. [This](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html) quite famous tutorial says that we are converting frames from native format to RGB .

Comment: Yes, but that's another, further, operation. I'm updating the answer, hope to be clearer...

Comment: Why dont we need a 'canvas' for pFrame ? The AVFrame of pFrame has data[] and linesize[] arrays . What are they pointing to , then ?

Comment: @Iserni ... Your explanation was very clear . Thanks a lot :)

Comment: great answer..if this wasn't there I would be beating my head for a long time. @lserni is there a any websource where i can read up on ffmpeg apart from the documentation. I'm trying to stream RTSP in iOS and working on some optimisations. Need some help here if you can.

Comment: Unfortunately these valid suggestions are now stale because AvPicture and all corresponding methods have been discontinuted

Comment: @Antonio well, if you *don't* have AvPicture, then neither can you have the original *problem* and all is OK :-) .
If you have a *different* (but similar) problem then ask a question and add a comment with a link to it here, and I'll try to respond as soon (and as well, which isn't much) as I can.

Comment: @LSerni Thanks! :) What I was wondering is if one can use AVFrame with _externally allocated_ buffers. Is it worth creating a question or is the answer an easy no? The aim is avoiding copies, the context: I would have the frame incoming as YUV, stored in some uchar buffer, and I would send it for dumping to a dedicated sub-library of my project, but I want to limit the dependency to ffmpeg to the sub-library in my project that does the data recording. (The project is much more complex, and recording of the input data is just an option sometimes I activate)

Comment: @Antonio the answer is a... *difficult no*. The problem is that  avcodec_alloc_frame() creates a typed structure, and the rest of ffmpeg expects that info to be there. And the typing details are in the library's innards -- you are not expected to poke in there (if the structure changed an your code *did not*... do I need to say more?).
A limited hack you can employ is to run avcodec_alloc_frame() *once*, and save its bulk data pointer, which is *the first pointer* in FF_COMMON_FRAME (see avcodec.h). You need the AV defaults to get how the memory is arranged, but then you can write there.

Comment: @LSerni Thank you for your very knowledgeable insight!

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg store the frame's pixel data in specific order within framebuffer. the storage depends on picture format (YUV, RGB,).

avpicture_fill() => this function takes the raw buffer and set various pointers of AVPicture structure.

Comment: These terms I am referring to are from the source code :  The AVFrame pointed to by 'pFrame' has data[] and linesize[] arrays . But then we didn't allocate any buffer for the pFrame before decoding the 'packet' and thus placing the frame received in the AVFrame pointed to by pFrame . What do these arrays point to ?

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg or similar libraries will not do an inplace buffer conversion. First thing it is about not loosing the original data and speed of working with different buffers. Secondly, if you do a lot of conversions, you can allocate the needed buffer beforehand.

Comment: Can you explain it in layman's terms ! I didn't understand that well . Also if possible , please commpare it with 'SOMETHING' which has implicit buffers :) Thanks .